# Out of 8 books, you want 3. You pick 4 at random. What are the chances you got at least two you wanted?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

**Problem**

In a bag there are 8 books you want. 3 of them are desirable. You pick 4 at random. What are the chances you get at least 2 of the 3 desired ones?

**My thoughts**

Presumably $P(\text{at least 2}) = P(2) + P(3)$.

The total number of combinations of books you can end up with, is $\binom84 = 70$.

Let's label the books with letters A-H, and let the three desired ones be A, B, C.

The possible combinations where you get all of them, would be ABCD, ABCE, ABCF, ABCG, ABCH. So a total of 5 combinations.

This gets us $P(3) = \frac5{70} = \frac1{14}$.

But I'm struggling with $P(2)$.

Comment: Hint:  argue that there are $\binom 32\times \binom 52$ ways to choose the four books such that exactly $2$ are desirable.

Comment: Ah of course. We want 2 from the 3 desirables, and 2 from the 5 non-desirables. So $P(2) = \frac{\binom32 \cdot \binom52}{\binom84}$, right?

Comment: Exactly.  $\quad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ah of course. We want 2 from the 3 desirables, and 2 from the 5 non-desirables.

Excatly!

$P(3)$ is the probability for obtaining 3 from 3 favoured books and 1 from 5 unfavoured, when selecting any 4 from all 8 books. This is what you were manually counting.

$$P(3)=\dfrac{\dbinom 33\dbinom 51}{\dbinom 84}=\dfrac{5}{70}$$

Likewise, $P(2)$ is the probability for obtaining 2 from 3 favoured books and 2 from 5 unfavoured, when selecting any 4 from all 8 books.

$$P(2)=\dfrac{\dbinom 32\dbinom 52}{\dbinom 84}=\dfrac{30}{70}$$

So...

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the number of desirable books you get is given by a [hypergeometric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) random variable.